# How to use SSL Protocol tlsv_1.2 in unity3d 5.5.3 version?

Tags: c#, .net, ssl, unity-game-engine, tls1.2

I have a requirement of using ssl protocol tlsv_1.2 in my unity3d project.
But as of now unity is only supporting up to tlsv_1.0 only.

Are there any workarounds to make use of tlsv_1.2 in my unity3d projects.

There are dll availabe which supports tlsv_1.2 , but those are of .net 4.5 or other version, but unity only supports .net 3.5 version libraries which inbuilt has no tlsv_1.2 protocol.

Answer (score 1):

> There are dll availabe which supports tlsv_1.2 , but those are of .net
>   4.5 or other version, but unity only supports .net 3.5 version libraries which inbuilt has no tlsv_1.2 protocol.

Download [*Unity 2017.1 beta*](https://unity3d.com/unity/beta) and you will have access to *.Net 4.6*. The final version will be released next month but the beta is working fine with  *.Net 4.5* and *.Net 4.6*.

---

To enabled .Net 4.6:

Go to *Edit* --> *Project Settings* --> *Player* --> *Other Settings* --> *Configuration* --> *Scripting Runtime Version* --> *.NET 4.6 Equivalent*

then

Go to *Edit* --> *Project Settings* --> *Player* --> *Other Settings* --> *Configuration* --> *Api Compatibility Level* --> *.NET 4.6*

Comment: At this point, it will work on most used platforms: Windows, Linux, Mac, iOS, Android, Windows Phone. Other platforms should be added very soon.

Comment: Ohkk thanks :), But currently I am using unity 5.5.3 version, Is there any way to implement tlsv_1.2 in this version of unity, Either including .net 4.5 library or ant other way ?

Comment: I haven't used "tslv_1.2" before but the way I port non compatible libraries is to download it to my Unity project then fix all the errors one by one by removing non supported C# features. It takes so much time but this depends on the size of the lib and how many non supported features are used.

Comment: Then may be tlsv_1.2 is not supported currently in unity, which asked me to remove that as well form dll

Comment: My last comment was talking about the source code not the DLL.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147423/discussion-between-djkp-and-programmer).